# If I my motherboard is SATAI, can it use SATAII hard drives?

Tags: sata

My motherboard has SATAI and I was wondering if I could buy SATAII hard drives and use it with it. I expect SATA I transfer speeds, but I wanted to make sure to see if that is okay to buy a new hard drive.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. SATA II interfaces are backwards compatible with SATA I on both host and drive.

Comment: To add more detail, SATAII drives will downscale to SATAI speeds.

Comment: This this apply to SATAIII too? SATAIII will downscale to I/II?

Comment: As far as I know, all SATA 1.5/3/6 drives are supposed to work with SATA 1.5/3/6 hosts (at the smaller maximum supported speed, of course). However there can be compatibility issues; for example I've known SATA 3 drives that only worked on SATA 1.5 hosts if you added a jumper.