# SATA I hard drive compatibility to SATA II motherboard.

Tags: hard-drive, motherboard, sata

I would like to buy a new motherboard for my computer since I'm in need of higher ram capacity. My computer is pretty old and my hard-drive is SATA I. All new motherboards I see mention that they have SATA II/ SATA III compatibility. Will my SATA I hard-drive be able to connect?

Comment: possible duplicate of [If I my motherboard is SATAI, can it use SATAII hard drives?](http://superuser.com/questions/202022/if-i-my-motherboard-is-satai-can-it-use-sataii-hard-drives), [Can I connect a SATA-II hard drive to a SATA-I connection?](http://superuser.com/questions/52001/can-i-connect-a-sata-ii-hard-drive-to-a-sata-i-connection?rq=1), [What's the difference between SATA and SATA-II (3.0 GB)?](http://superuser.com/questions/14790/whats-the-difference-between-sata-and-sata-ii-3-0-gb)

Answer (score 1):

Yeah it will work. But only with the speed of SATA I.

Comment: Keep in mind, most of the newer versions of (anything) would support to the older versions. But not Vice Versa ;)