# Will any SATA hard drive work with any SATA motherboard?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd

This is the motherboard I have:
http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16813188024
My question is can I use any SATA hdd/ssd with this? ( as In SATA I, II, or III?)
will a 6 Gb/s hdd work with 3 Gb/s motherboard?

Comment: How about specifics? Do you have this motherboard?  If you do is your question, specifically, will a SATA III device work with it?  If so update your question.

Comment: That is the motherboard I have. My question is can I use a SATA III with SATA I MotherBoard and vice versa?

Comment: I don't believe the SATA interface spec is motherboard specific.  The SATA interface is backwards compatible.

Comment: You don't have a SATA I motherboard though.

Comment: possible duplicate of [6Gb/s SATA hard drive with 3Gb/s SATA port?](http://superuser.com/questions/242423/6gb-s-sata-hard-drive-with-3gb-s-sata-port), [If I my motherboard is SATAI, can it use SATAII hard drives?](http://superuser.com/questions/202022/if-i-my-motherboard-is-satai-can-it-use-sataii-hard-drives)

Answer (score 11):

Yes. By design, all newer SATA standards are backwards compatible with older SATA standards and will fall back to the slower speed such that they will work.
So it doesn't matter whether it is a SATA 1 controller with a SATA 3 drive or a SATA 3 controller with a SATA 1 drive, or any combination with SATA 2 as well, they should all work together just fine.

The only exception in my experience is that some older SATA drives require a 3.3 volt supply, while most drives work fine without it. This is a power supply issue not a SATA version issue.

To clarify, a 6 Gb/s hdd will work with a 3 Gb/s motherboard, but it will only work at the slower speed.
This is great if you want to go ahead and get some faster drives now and upgrade to a faster mainboard later.
I have had no problems moving SATA drives between different computers.

Comment: There were some early sata II drives that had a jumper on them to make them backward compatible to sata I for some first gen sata motherboards, which required you to know that you had to move the jumper before it would work.